# How to use the 'hex' encoding in Python 3.2 or higher?

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x, hex

In Python 2, to get a string representation of the hexadecimal digits in a string, you could do

```
>>> '\x12\x34\x56\x78'.encode('hex')
'12345678'
```

In Python 3, that doesn't work anymore (tested on Python 3.2 and 3.3):

```
>>> '\x12\x34\x56\x78'.encode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: hex
```

There is at least [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7795102/20670) here on SO that mentions that the `hex` codec has been removed in Python 3. But then, [according to the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), it was reintroduced in Python 3.2, as a "bytes-to-bytes mapping".

However, I don't know how to get these "bytes-to-bytes mappings" to work:

```
>>> b'\x12'.encode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

And the docs don't mention that either (at least not where I looked). I must be missing something simple, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2340358/1298523

Comment: I would argue against closing this as a dupe. This question is specifically about Python 3.2 where the `hex` codec is officially back (but harder to find). The linked question is about Python 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python 3.5 you can simply use `.hex()`:

```
>>> b'\x12\x34\x56\x78'.hex()
'12345678'
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to go via the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module and the [`hex_codec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms) codec (or its `hex` alias if available<sup>*</sup>):

```
codecs.encode(b'\x12', 'hex_codec')
```

<sub>* From the documentation: *"Changed in version 3.4: Restoration of the aliases for the binary transforms"*.</sub>

Comment: Don't you mean `codecs.encode(b'\x12', 'hex_codec')`? With `'hex'` I only get `LookupError: unknown encoding: hex`

Comment: The docs say `hex` is an alias in 3.2, but my 3.2.3 installation had the same error.

Comment: While I can't find a reference to a bugfix, it looks like `hex` is working again as of 3.4.

Comment: Thankyou ! you save my day :)

Answer (score 14):

Yet another way using [`binascii.hexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'\x12\x34\x56\x78')
b'12345678'
```

Comment: So you took a glance at the so-called dupe, yes? :)

Comment: No, that's the way I usually do it :)

Answer (score 10):

Using [`base64.b16encode()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b16encode):

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b16encode(b'\x12\x34\x56\x78')
b'12345678'
```

Answer (score 9):

[`binascii`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) methods are easier by the way:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> x=b'test'
>>> x=binascii.hexlify(x)
>>> x
b'74657374'
>>> y=str(x,'ascii')
>>> y
'74657374'
>>> x=binascii.unhexlify(x)
>>> x
b'test'
>>> y=str(x,'ascii')
>>> y
'test'
```

Comment: `str(x,'ascii')` is better spelt `x.decode('ascii')`

Comment: `binascii` also seems faster, for anyone who cares.